# Getting Subscription ID with Resource Group without setting az context

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a tenant with multiple subscriptions.
When I first login using Connect-AzAccount, it shows a message "TenantId 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx' contains more than one active subscription. First one will be selected for further use. To select another subscription, use Set-AzContext."

But I want to be able to do `Get-AzResourceGroup -name 'abcd'`.

The problem is resource group abcd is not under the first selected subscription selected from the login command.

I want to progromatically `Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ResourcegroupName"` to retrieve the subscriptionID without setting az context as it defeats the purpose.

tried to clear the context `clear-azContext` but that signs me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to progromatically Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ResourcegroupName" to retrieve the subscriptionID without setting az context as it defeats the purpose.

After reproducing from my end, Using the below script I could able to achieve your requirement.

```
$ResourceGroupName = Read-Host "Enter the resource group name you are searching for"
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
    $subscriptionId = $_.SubscriptionId
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
    (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName | ForEach-Object {     
        If ($ResourceGroupName -eq $_) {
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                Subscription  = $subscriptionName
                SubscriptionId = $subscriptionId
                ResourceGroup = $_
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Comment: Greatly appreciate it. The only downside of looping through all the subscriptions, is I have over a 1000 subscriptions to manage.
But the concept works great. Thanks!

Comment: In general, there is no way to achieve this without looping as there may be multiple resource groups of the same name in different subscriptions, and AFAIK there is no dedicated API for resource groups lookup across subscriptions.